# Boost.Asio: What's the Behavior of a deadline_timer with 0 Millisecond Expiration

Tags: boost, timer, boost-asio

What the behavior of a `deadline_timer` whose expiration is 0 milliseconds?

In my code, I have:

```
boost::asio::io_service ios;
...
boost::asio::deadline_timer ptimer(ios);
ptimer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(duration)); // Duration might be 0 sometimes
boost::system::error_code ec;
ptimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&SomeTimeOutHandler, this, ec));
```

I found that if `duration == 0`, the handler `SomeTimeOutHandler` never gets called.

I want it gets called.

However, if I change to `duration == 1`, the handler does get called.

So what the exact behavior it should be when the `deadline_timer`'s expiration is 0?

***Edit:***

But the following HelloWorld test program is working (suggested by @Roger):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void SomeTimeOutHandler(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    if (ec)
    {
        std::cout << "SomeTimeOutHandler error_code" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "I'm in good shape" << std::endl;
    }
}

void Test(int duration)
{
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer ptimer(ios);

    ptimer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(duration));
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    ptimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&SomeTimeOutHandler, ec));

    ios.run();

//    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(duration * 2 + 1000));
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Test(10); // Test(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The handler should get fired. Have you tried this in a simple test program? One thing, pass **boost::asio::placeholders::error** in the bind instead of local `ec`, i.e. `boost::bind(&SomeTimeOutHandler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error)`

Comment: @RogerStewart, hmmm, you are right, I made a test program, it's working.  There must be some other logic issue in my real-world application.

Comment: @Peter post your real-world code then. Reducing it down to a complete example demonstrating the problem is an important debugging skill.